# CORS problems when using Caddy 2 and express

Tags: express, cors, caddy, caddyfile

I've got a nodejs-express server running behind a [Caddy 2](https://caddyserver.com/) server as a reverse-proxy.

Caddy is running on a docker with the following configuration in docker-compose

```yaml
  caddy:
    image: caddy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - main-network
    volumes:
      - "./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile"
```

With the following Caddyfile:

```
my-nice-site.com {
  reverse_proxy /* server:4030
}
```

The setup is working nicely when serving a webpage and the API, however, I'm getting into CORS problems the moment I try to access using a javascript with a different ORIGIN.

I have set up CORS in the express server using express [cors middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and it works ok when using on its own, but I keep getting that when running it behind Caddy, so I guess there is some configuration I need to make in my Caddyfile to allow cors but I couldn't find anything that worked for my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem:
The headers were correctly set up by express, and I was getting them when making requests with curl or Postman without changing anything in Caddy.

The problem ended up being that I was making requests to `http`, Caddy was redirecting these to `https`, which is no problem for `GET` requests sent from Postman, but [Preflight-requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) (`OPTIONS`) do not support redirects, and because Caddy was making the redirection, it was not reaching express (and CORS setup), throwing the error.

Finally, the solution was simply making my requests to `https://my-nice-server.com`

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Silly thing, and easy to forget to check. Thanks!